# Seekbar issues (prevent thumbs to move)

Tags: android, scrollbar, progress, seekbar

I'm increasing the font of textview based on progress bar...and while the width of textview <= device width, the font increases with the bar...and when the limit reach...the font stop increasing.

The problem is the thumbs, it's moves freely. When i move it fast from position 0 to max...the condition are ignored (textview width become greater than device width).

Anyone knows how to prevent seekbar thumbs from move after certain position?

Ex.: seekbar.max(10)...when progress reach 4 i don't want the thumbs moves after it.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried calculating the max size  of the textview at forehand? (get device width and map that on textview width) Have you tried implementing an onSeekBarChanged listener?

Comment: I used OnSeekBarChangedListener and what i do is exactly what you mean, but inside OnChanged. The problem i got is the font...i`m using MONOTYPE and sometimes it increase the height instead of the width...and for my project just this font works correctly. It increase 74 points on textview width everytime the font increase, except when the height increase instead of width. But thanks..i`m getting close to the solution and when i get it i'll post here.